# How to estimate air velocity at turbine in turbojet?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, aerospace-engineering, propulsion, aviation

I am designing a small turbojet. I wanted to know how to calculate the air volume expansion to predict the outlet velocity of air towards the turbine. Theoretically, I wouldn't know the flame temperature. So, starting from there, what is the flow of work ?

Thank You.